# Error While opening a page in My Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

## Server Error in '/Court Case' Application.

*Keyword not supported: 'userid'.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'userid'.

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'userid'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +6363422
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +122
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +113
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +35
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +64
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +44
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +150
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +27
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +261
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8009; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string to connect to the database is faulted. It contains `userid` while it should be `user id` (with the space between).

See [connectionstrings.com](https://connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for examples.